# pf error - "No ALTQ support in the kernel"... What does this mean?

Tags: macos, firewall, pf

I am running Mac OS X.  I would like to be able to configure pf because it seems to be more sophisticated and flexible than the default Mac OS X firewall that you can access through the System Preferences.  I tried using some pf commands and got some errors that I don't understand.

```
bash-3.2$ sudo pfctl -s rules
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple/*" all
bash-3.2$ sudo pfctl -s states
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
```

I looked up ALTQ on Wikipedia and it seems to be a queueing program that does statistical multiplexing of packets at the kernel level.  It is the kernel module that BSD systems use for queueing of packets.  And the Mac OS X kernel apparently doesn't support it.

Okay, so this doesn't really make sense.  Why would Mac OS X include the BSD pf firewall but not include support for the queueing software necessary to make that firewall work?  Isn't that kind of counter-productive?  There must be some way to turn support for ALTQ on, but I have no idea what it is.  I'm not even entirely sure what ALTQ is.  Is it a loadable kernel module that I have to load using the `kextload` command?  Or is the problem that it's already there but the kernel is just incompatible with it.  I am utterly confused.

Comment: What version of OS X?

Comment: @Spiff I get this with 10.9.5

Comment: Same here with 10.12.6

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable Firewall:
<kbd>System Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>Security & Privacy</kbd> -> <kbd>Firewall</kbd> -> <kbd>Turn On Firewall</kbd>
(Under the hood it doing `sudo pfctl -E`)

if you would try after that : `sudo pfctl -s info` it shouldn't blame about ALTQ

Comment: For OSX 10.11.6 this wasn't working for me. It is still printing: No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled

Comment: Both firewalls seem unrelated. In previous versions of OS X, the firewall accessible in `System Preferences` was the "Application Firewall" which was independent of the low level firewall ipfw (which was replaced by pf). More information is available at [PF on Mac OS X](https://pleiades.ucsc.edu/hyades/PF_on_Mac_OS_X).

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have mistaken the output of your command:

```
sudo pfctl -s rules
```

The ouput lists a warning:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
```

With further information regarding that warning:

```
ALTQ related functions disabled
```

It then goes on to list the active rules as requested:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple/*" all
```

You can find some further information, including the meaning of the output above, here:

https://krypted.com/mac-security/a-cheat-sheet-for-using-pf-in-os-x-lion-and-up/

I use Little Snitch on macOS, which as I remember, but could be wrong, uses `pf` for the backend.

ALTQ is used for traffic shaping.  Here is information on traffic shaping (and ALTQ) for the pfSense open source project.  pfSense, as its name suggests, utilizes `pf` and is based on FreeBSD, which macOS is also (to an extent).  I only give it to provide to information about ALTQ (and what `pf` is capable of in relation).

https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/book/trafficshaper/index.html

I would venture to comment that ALTQ traffic shaping might be better served at an edge firewall/router than on a workstation, and no great loss that it is not enabled on macOS (as Apple has abandoned it as a meaningful server operating system and focused on consumer desktop application usage).  YMMV.